# TLS module in ProFTPD

Tags: ubuntu, tls, proftpd

I wanted to configure ProFTPD in Ubuntu 16.04
I've installed the proftpd-basic package (the only one I could find in the repositories):

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep proftpd
proftpd-basic                   install
```

But this package has apparently no TLS module compiled in:

```
$ proftpd -l 
Compiled-in modules:
  mod_core.c
  mod_xfer.c
  mod_rlimit.c
  mod_auth_unix.c
  mod_auth_file.c
  mod_auth.c
  mod_ls.c
  mod_log.c
  mod_site.c
  mod_delay.c
  mod_facts.c
  mod_dso.c
  mod_ident.c
  mod_auth_pam.c
  mod_readme.c
  mod_memcache.c
  mod_cap.c
  mod_ctrls.c
  mod_lang.c
$ proftpd -l | grep tls
$
```

I can't find any package for the tls module in the repositories, either:

```
$ apt-cache search proftpd-mod
proftpd-basic - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - binaries
proftpd-mod-autohost - ProFTPD module mod_autohost
proftpd-mod-case - ProFTPD module mod_case
proftpd-mod-clamav - ProFTPD module mod_clamav
proftpd-mod-dnsbl - ProFTPD module mod_dnsbl
proftpd-mod-fsync - ProFTPD module mod_fsync
proftpd-mod-geoip - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - GeoIP module
proftpd-mod-ldap - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - LDAP module
proftpd-mod-msg - ProFTPD module mod_msg
proftpd-mod-mysql - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - MySQL module
proftpd-mod-odbc - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - ODBC module
proftpd-mod-pgsql - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - PostgreSQL module
proftpd-mod-sqlite - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - SQLite3 module
proftpd-mod-tar - ProFTPD module mod_tar
proftpd-mod-vroot - ProFTPD module mod_vroot
```

Do I need to compile proftpd from source with the tls module switch or is there any quicker way to get TLS enabled?

Comment: What does `proftpd -V` show?  Oftentimes modules like `mod_tls` are compiled as _shared_ modules, which won't be listed using `proftpd -l`.  Alternatively, you could use `proftpd -vv`, which shows all modules, _including those loaded dynamically via config file_, to see if `mod_tls` is present.

Comment: you're right, it's a shared module --with-shared=...:mod_tls  . But so far I've been unable to get encryption working, I will revise the conf files again ...